# How to use fieldValueConverter in QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat

Tags: python, qgis

I have a shapefile with 197 fields but I only want to keep about 7 fields. When I delete fields using QgsVectorlayer.provider().deleteAttributes(), it takes me about 20 minutes. I wonder if it will be faster if I use QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat to make a new layer with only those 7 fields. However, I am really struggling with the syntax, in particular, what the fieldValueConverter argument accepts.

I’ve been looking at documentation (https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter_1_1FieldValueConverter.html, https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#ae54dce04a5fc1a570b6c4c4f7dfa064d) but I’m having a lot of trouble understanding them. I also don’t understand what the error code is trying to tell me. The thing I’m most confident about is that the fieldValueConverter probably isn’t as simple as just accepting a list of field names…
I am using QGIS 3.4.4.

What I have:

`project = QgsProject.instance()
origlayer  = project.mapLayersByName("data_layer")[0]`

`keeplist = ["field1”, “field2”, “field3"] #example fields to keep
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer = origlayer  , filename = "FINAL_layer", fieldValueConverter = keeplist)`

Error code:

`TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: 'fieldValueConverter' is not a valid keyword argument
  overload 2: 'fieldValueConverter' is not a valid keyword argument
  overload 3: 'fieldValueConverter' is not a valid keyword argument`

Comment: You can use the key next to the q (\`) to encase code like `this`. (one \` at the beginning and end.

Comment: Thanks! Quotes added

Comment: Hi @elasticbread, did you find a solution to this problem? I'm trying to do the same but I can't get it